# Simple distance calculation in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, distance

So imagine a spacetime with the Schwarzschild metric:

$$ds^2=-c^2\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)dt\otimes dt+\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)}dr\otimes dr+r^2\left(d\theta\otimes d\theta+\sin^2\theta d\phi\otimes d\phi\right)$$

Now we have the following trajectory:

[image: Trajectory in brown. Tangent vectors in red.]

The trajectory to cover is in brown. In order to calculate the total distance (it moves through all dimensions, in time, radial, azimuthal...), we approximate the path as an array of $\lambda$ tangent vectors that we painted in red. With this approach, we would like an infinite amount of $\lambda_d$ infinitesimal vectors and then integrate over them like $\int_{p_o}^{p_1}||\lambda_d||d\lambda$ from point $p_o$ to $p_1$.

I have seen on the Internet many cases in which they calculate the proper time or proper distance, but I would like to know if there is some way to obtain an enclosed formula that groups all parameters, maybe at the cost of some assumptions (for example, that the trajectory is a line from the point of the traveller).

How would you calculate the distance from these two $p_o$ to $p_1$, including all parameters there? (That is to say, including $r$, $c$, $2GM$, $r^2$ and $\sin^2 \theta$). Can it be done? What do you need to assume in order for it to work?

The problem I have is to parameterize the differentials $dt\otimes dt$, $dr\otimes dr$, $d\theta\otimes d\theta$ and $d\psi\otimes d\psi$. Can you simply say:

$dt\otimes dt=dr\otimes dr=d\theta\otimes d\theta=d\psi\otimes d\psi=d\lambda\otimes d\lambda$

And integrate?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what difficulty you're encountering here.  Isn't the answer just "write the coordinates as functions of $\lambda$, find $ds$ in terms of $d\lambda$, and integrate"?  Just like for any other arc length problem from a second-year calculus class?  Can you edit your question to elaborate on what part of the process you're having trouble with?

Comment: The problem I find is how to put $ds^2$ in terms of $d\lambda$. Do you simply replace, for example, $dt\otimes dt$ and $dr\otimes dr$ by $d\lambda\otimes d\lambda$? I have seen some people integrating first the proper time and then the proper distance and operating separately. Can you really just replace the $dsomething^2$ by $d\lambda^2$ and you're good to go?

Comment: More or less;  technically you replace $dt^2$ by $(dt/d\lambda)^2 d\lambda^2$ & similarly for the other terms in the line element.  See [Javier's answer below.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/764439/81133)

Comment: Hmm... So if you consider $(dt/d\lambda)=1$, meaning $t$ varies exactly in the same proportion as $\lambda$ when changing the latter, then that's it? You do that for the other coordinates and done?

Comment: Basically, yes.  If $t$ is the parameter for your curve then $dt/d\lambda = 1$.  You have the freedom to choose other parameters for the curve if you like, though.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only general notion of total distance along a curve in general relativity is the proper time (or interval)

$$\Delta \tau = \int \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}} d\lambda,$$

where I've chosen the sign corresponding to a timelike curve. You could replace the minus sign with an absolute value to include also spacelike curves, which have a proper distance instead. This may not match our intuitive sense of distance, because it gives zero for a lightlike curve, but it's all there is.

Or at least, it's all there is if you want a general definition, which is coordinate invariant and applicable to every metric. In a specific given spacetime you might choose some other definition, which depends on the coordinate system used but may be physically relevant there.